# SurfaceTexture has been abandoned / Could not dequeue gralloc buffer / flushSurface() fail

Tags: android, android-camera

My camera app processes frames with OpenCV before displaying them.  Although the camera preview works, the logcat is spammed with the errors:

> E/BufferQueue(22797): [unnamed-22797-0] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture
>   has been abandoned! E/SecCameraHardware(2078): Could not dequeue
>   gralloc buffer!
>   05-03 13:29:12.716 E/ISecCameraHardware(2078): bool android::ISecCameraHardware::previewThread()::flushSurface() fail

Here is the relevant code, adapted from OpenCV's sample code:

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new PreviewCallback() {
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        synchronized (CameraView.this) {
            System.arraycopy(data, 0, mFrame, 0, data.length);
            CameraView.this.notify();
        }
        camera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
    }
});
```

[...]

```
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight, 
    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

try {
    mCamera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(10));
} catch (IOException e) {};

mCamera.startPreview();
```

[...]

```
public void run() {
    mThreadRun = true;
    Log.i(TAG, "Starting processing thread");
    while (mThreadRun) {
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                this.wait();
                processFrame(mFrame);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Canvas canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
        if (canvas != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,
                    (canvas.getWidth() - mFrameWidth) / 2,
                    (canvas.getHeight() - mFrameHeight) / 2, null);
            mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006337/opencv-android-bufferqueue-error-surface-texture-has-been-abandoned) relating to this error, but the suggested solution - creating the bitmap for display before setting the preview texture - has no effect for me.

Comment: Seems to be an OpenCV problem. Check [this][1] post.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006337/opencv-android-bufferqueue-error-surface-texture-has-been-abandoned