# Why am I getting surfaceTexture.updateTexImage() on a null object reference?

Tags: opengl-es, decode, android-mediacodec, glsurfaceview, render-to-texture

I am trying to decode a mp4 with MediaCodec and render it with GLSurfaceView. To MediaCodec configure() I am passing the created Surface with SurfaceTexture. On the SurfaceTexture I am calling a Listener and synchronize it in the OnDrawFrame method and calling surfacetexture.upadteTexImage(); The result is surfaceTexture.updateTexImage() on a null object reference.
I am wondering how is this even possible? Since the Listener gives the message that there is a frame available, how can he return null?
I must say that I have a problem at all to configure the MediaCodec with OpenGlES. Firstly I thought that this because of Samsung device decoder, but when I tried to decode to a SurfaceView it worked well.

```
SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(textures[1]);
    surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

    surfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(new SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
                synchronized (mediaPlayerObject) {
                    mediaPlayeUpdate = true;
                    mediaPlayerObject.notifyAll();
                }
       }
   });


public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        GLES20.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        synchronized (mediaPlayerObject) {
            surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
            mediaPlayeUpdate = false;
        }
```

And I am calling this on surfaceChanged(GL...)

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public void run() {
    mediaExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
    try {
        mediaExtractor.setDataSource("sdcard/nagranie2.mp4");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mediaExtractor.getTrackCount(); i++) {
        MediaFormat format = mediaExtractor.getTrackFormat(i);
        String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
        if (mime.startsWith("video/")) {
            mediaExtractor.selectTrack(i);
            try {
                decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            decoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (decoder == null) {
        Log.e("DecodeActivity", "Can't find video info!");
        return;
    }
    decoder.start();


    ByteBuffer[] decoderInputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
    ByteBuffer[] decoderOutputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();

    MediaCodec.BufferInfo info1 = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    boolean isOES = false;
    long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();


    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        if (!isOES) {
            int intBufIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
            if (intBufIndex >= 0) {
                ByteBuffer inputBuffer = decoderInputBuffers[intBufIndex];
                int chunkSize = mediaExtractor.readSampleData(inputBuffer, 0);
                if (chunkSize < 0) {
                    decoder.queueInputBuffer(intBufIndex, 0, 0, 0L, decoder.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                    isOES = true;

                } else {

                    decoder.queueInputBuffer(intBufIndex, 0, chunkSize, mediaExtractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
                    mediaExtractor.advance();

                }
            }
        }

        int decoderStatus = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info1, 10000);
        switch (decoderStatus)
        {
            case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                decoderOutputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
                break;

            case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                break;

            case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
                break;
            default:
                ByteBuffer byteBuffer = decoderOutputBuffers[decoderStatus];
             /*   while (info1.presentationTimeUs / 1000 > System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs) {
                    try {
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }*/
                decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decoderStatus, true);
                break;

        }



        if ((info1.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
            break;
        }

    }

    decoder.stop();
    decoder.release();
    mediaExtractor.release();
}
```

Comment: You need to hold a strong reference to your SurfaceTexture so it it doesn't get garbage collected.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807086/surfacetexture-has-been-abandoned

Comment: how do you mean? Is SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture() not a strong reference? Is this wrong what I wrote in the code above?

Comment: It depends on where you declare that variable, if it is inside a method then no its not. the reference is local to the method and may be garbage collected after the method returns.

Comment: hey, you are right, I made the surfacetexture object member of the class and it works. I would like to accept your answer!